# Retrieving part of a string using a delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

Okay So I am creating an application but I'm not sure how to get certain parts of the string. I have read In a file as such:

```
*tp*|21394398437984|163600
*2*|AAA|1234567894561236|STOP|20140527|Success||Automated|DSPRN1234567
*2*|AAA|1234567894561237|STOP|20140527|Success||Automated|DPSRN1234568
*3*|2
```

I need to read the lines beginning with *2* so I done:

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.dat")));
while (s.hasNext()) {
   String str1 = s.nextLine ();
   if(str1.startsWith("*2*")) {
      System.out.print(str1);
   }
}
```

So this will read the whole line I'm fine with that, Now my issue is I need to extract the 2nd line beginning with numbers  the 4th with numbers the 5th with success and the 7th(DPSRN).

I was thinking about using a String delimiter with | as the delimiter but I'm not sure where to go after this any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `String.split("|")`, it will give you an array - String[]

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
String test="*2*|AAA|1234567894561236|STOP|20140527|Success||Automated|DSPRN1234567";
String tok[]=test.split("\\|");
for(String s:tok){
 System.out.println(s);
 }
```

**Output :**

```
*2*
AAA
1234567894561236
STOP
20140527
Success

Automated
DSPRN1234567
```

What you require will be placed at `tok[2]`, `tok[4]`, `tok[5]` and `tok[8]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the returned line based on your search, which would return an array of `String` elements where you can retrieve your elements based on their index:

```java
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.dat")));
String searchLine = "";
while (s.hasNext()) {
   searchLine = s.nextLine();
   if(searchLine.startsWith("*2*")) {
      break;
   }
}
String[] strs = searchLine.split("|");
String secondArgument = strs[2];
String forthArgument = strs[4];
String fifthArgument = strs[5];
String seventhArgument = strs[7];
System.out.println(secondArgument);
System.out.println(forthArgument);
System.out.println(fifthArgument);
System.out.println(seventhArgument);
```